# Excel VBA Range.AutoFilter filtering for equal sign ("=")

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I hava a table `tbl_recommendations` that contains the following values in column 13: `--`, `-`, `=`, `+`, `++`.

Now, I would like to filter for `=`, `+`, `++`. This is working fine manually, however, I am facing some problems when using VBA regarding filtering for `=`. Simply using the macro recorder, it gives me the following code:

```
Sub Test()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_recommendations").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
    Criteria1:=Array("+", "++", " = "), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

When executing this macro, it only filters for `+` and `++`, but not for `=`. What's the trick?

Comment: Did you tried without the spaces sourrounding the`=`?

Comment: It seems that using `"="` is saved for the filter to show only blanks for the specified Field by using: `Criteria1:="="`, read here http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm

Comment: @ShaiRado You're right. However, I expect there must exist a possibility as I am able to filter for `=` manually.

Comment: @Veve...it doesn't matter if I delete the surrounding spaces. No version is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on recording a macro while doing the filtering and seems to work:

```
Sub Test()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_recommendations").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
    Criteria1:=Array("+", "++", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: ...I can't confirm that your solution is working correctly. It is not showing the lines value `=`.

Comment: It works if `"="` has no spaces but the IDE seems a bit flakey when entering `"="` as it sometimes inexplicably enters the spaces before and after the equal sign.  Try deleting your Test sub, start a new Test2 sub and copy/paste the above command into it.

Answer (score 0):

it's weird but if you run the macro recorder to filter for "+", "++" and " = " (with spaces) criteria, then:

- it writes the following code:

  ```
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_recommendations").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
  Criteria1:=Array("+", "++", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  ```

  so it deletes the "spaces" before and after the "=" character
- it correctly filters the table showing records with "+", "++" and " = " (with spaces) content in table 13th column

but if you *run* that macro it doesn't filter " = " (with spaces) records anymore !

assuming there must be some *witchcraft* involving filter and "=" character, you can baffle it with this little workaround:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_recommendations").Range
    .columns(13).Replace what:=" = ", Replacement:="|=|", lookat:=xlWhole '<--| substitute "forbidden" " = " criteria with a "valid" one
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array("+", "++", "|=|"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter with "valid" criteria

        ' your code to act on filtered cells
        '....

    .columns(13).Replace what:="|=|", Replacement:=" = ", lookat:=xlWhole '<--| finally bring " = " back in place!
End With
```

Comment: @Andi, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add an additional equal sign before each of the characters and it seems to work:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tbl_recommendations").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
Criteria1:=Array("=+", "=++", "=="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```